# Why am I getting a null object?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to get JSON data from `https://newsapi.org/v1/articles` with Retrofit, but I'm new to it and it's been quite confusing so far.

From what I can tell, I've managed to establish a successful connection. However, for some reason I haven't been able to identify yet, Retrofit doesn't map the data from the JSON strings to my `NewsAPI` class.

I'll post the code that I'm currently using, and I'm hoping someone can help me figure this out. Thanks!

`Activity.java`:

```
final TextView tvTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
String url = "https://newsapi.org";

NewsAPI_Interface client = NewsAPI_Adapter.createService(NewsAPI_Interface.class);
Call<List<NewsAPI>> call = client.getData("techcrunch", "APIkeygoeshere");

call.enqueue(new Callback<List<NewsAPI>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<NewsAPI>> call, Response<List<NewsAPI>> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    tvTest.setText(response.body().toString());

                    for (NewsAPI news: response.body()) {
                        System.out.println(news.source + " (" + news.status + ")");
                        tvTest.setText(news.source + " (" + news.status + ")");
                    }
                } else {
                    tvTest.setText("It's null, " + response.errorBody().toString() + ", " + call.request().url());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<NewsAPI>> call, Throwable t) {
                tvTest.setText("An error ocurred!");
            }
        });
```

`NewsAPI.java`:

```
public class NewsAPI {
    String status;
    String source;

public NewsAPI (String status, String source) {
        this.status = status;
        this.source = source;
    }
}
```

`NewsAPI_Interface.java`:

```
public interface NewsAPI_Interface {
    @GET("/v1/articles")
    Call<List<NewsAPI>> getData(@Query("source") String source, @Query("api_Key") String api_key);
}
```

`NewsAPI_Adapter.java`:

```
public class NewsAPI_Adapter {
    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I recall, you can only use `response.body()` once from the `onResponse` method

Comment: Are you using proguard ?

Comment: Also, `@Query("api_Key")` should be `apiKey` if I am reading the right. https://newsapi.org/

Comment: And the callback is incorrectly defined. You aren't expecting a list, you are expecting a single `NewsAPI` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I can tell, I've managed to establish a successful connection

Well, you are ignoring the Throwable here, where you error would be output.

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<List<NewsAPI>> call, Throwable t) {
    tvTest.setText("An error ocurred!");
}
```

The response you are expecting looks like this

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "source": "techcrunch",
    ...
```

The `{` there starts *an object*, not a `List`, therefore, you should define your interface differently. Then the documentation says the API key is added to the URL with `apiKey`, so change that.

```
public interface NewsAPI_Interface {
    @GET("/v1/articles")
    Call<NewsAPI> getData(@Query("source") String source, @Query("apiKey") String api_key);
}
```

(You need to define another object for an `Article` class. But that is a Gson problem, not Retrofit)

Finally, I remember reading somewhere that `response.body()` should only be called once.

```
Call<NewsAPI> call = client.getData("techcrunch", "APIkeygoeshere");

call.enqueue(new Callback<NewsAPI>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<NewsAPI>> call, Response<List<NewsAPI>> response) {
        final NewsAPI responseBody = response.body();
        if (responseBody != null) {
            tvTest.setText(responseBody.toString());

            String news = news.source + " (" + news.status + ")";
            Log.i("responseBody", news);
            tvTest.setText(news);

        } else {
            tvTest.setText("It's null, " + response.errorBody().toString() + ", " + call.request().url());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<NewsAPI>> call, Throwable t) {
        tvTest.setText("An error ocurred!");
        Log.e("news Error", t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working now! I've also successfully implemented the missing `Articles` class that was needed for the JSON array to get mapped, by using an `ArrayList<Articles>` on the respective variable of the `NewsAPI` class. Just leaving it out here for future reference.

Comment: Hi Kalz i have followed up to this point how did you get the ArrayList<Articles> from the response,i am using the same api